# Excel sort by similar cell data

Tags: excel, list, sorting

So I have this list of data that i need to compare 2 spreadsheets with. Im going to simplify it with a list like below(Column A being a part number, and column B being a quantity):

Spreadsheet 1:

```
Red     1
Blue    2
Green   1
Orange  6
Yellow  8
```

Spreadsheet 2:

```
Red     1
Green   1
Blue    2
Orange  6
Yellow  8
Silver  2
Brown   3
```

Now what i would like my output to be:

```
Red     1
Blue    2
Green   1
Orange  6
Yellow  8
Silver  2
Brown   3
```

Notice that im sorting it so that list 2 aligns with list one, and if list 2 contains things that are not on list 1 it puts it at the bottom(preferably vice-versa compatible). Im not sure if this is even possible, but if it is it will GREATLY decrease my workload so any help is MUCH appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can't concat theses spreadsheet and make dynamic table ?

Comment: Im not very good at using excel so some of the advanced features elude me. No i haven't tried either of these.

Comment: Xire, i cant do that because i need to compare 2 parts orders to see if i need to add more parts, or if i ordered too many.